how to import shared css with Styled-components
Im using styled-components in my react project. I want to create a shared loading background. I have the following definition:
const loadingAnimation = keyframes`
0% {
  background-position: 95% 95%;
}
50% {
  background-position: 25% 25%;
}
100% {
  background-position: 25% 25%;
}
`;

export const LoadingBackgroundStyle = css`
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -60deg,
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary600},
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary600},
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary600},
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary700},
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary600},
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary600},
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary700}
  );
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: ${loadingAnimation} 1.25s linear infinite;
`;


and then I am using it like this:
import styled from "styled-components";

import { LoadingBackgroundStyle } from ".../PerformerInfoCard.styled";

export const SpotifyWrapper = styled.div``;

export const SkeletonPlayer = styled.div`
  height: ${(props) => props.$height}px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: ${({ $borderRadius }) => $borderRadius};
  ${LoadingBackgroundStyle}
`;

`;


for some reason its not showing the background style. It works fine when I define LoadingBackgroundStyle in the same file as SkeletonPlayer. What is happening here?
I tried defining the css in the same file and that did not work.

Theres three dots in the import path
import { LoadingBackgroundStyle } from ".../PerformerInfoCard.styled";

We don't know your file structure, but I presume this should be either:
import { LoadingBackgroundStyle } from "../PerformerInfoCard.styled";

or:
import { LoadingBackgroundStyle } from "./../PerformerInfoCard.styled";

